# Bootstrap carousel and responsiveness

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a website where I display some users' pictures. The pictures have a squared shape and a fixed size (100x100 px). I would like to create a carousel if there is not enough space to display all the user's pictures in a single line. And I would like this carousel be activated/deactivated if I resize my browser's window.

I don't know if it's possible easily and if bootstrap's carousel is the best choice !

Thanks in advance for any advices !

Comment: I have just a basic bootstrap carousel but I don't think it's the good tool for that. The fact that the html controls how many pictures are displayed (with the `item` class) doesn't make me feel like it's possible without a lot of hackery ! And I don't find a lot of ideas on google..!

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want to achieve?

https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/QvvowE

```js
var isCarouselPaused = false;

$( window ).on( 'load resize', function() {
  if ( document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 768 ) {
    if ( !isCarouselPaused ) {
      $( '#myCarousel' ).carousel('pause');
      isCarouselPaused = true;
    }
  } else {
    if ( isCarouselPaused ) {
      $( '#myCarousel' ).carousel('cycle');
      isCarouselPaused = false;
    }
  };
});
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .carousel .item {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 12px;
  }
  .carousel-control, 
  .carousel-indicators {
    display: none;
  }
}

/* Make the images wide and responsive. */
.carousel-inner img {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

/* Decorations */  
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active"><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100/fc3/fff/?text=1" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100/693/fff/?text=2" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100/369/fff/?text=3" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100/f63/fff/?text=4" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100/936/fff/?text=5" alt=""></div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span><span class="sr-only">Next</span></a>
  </div>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Kind of, but not only for mobile resolution. I found https://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v1.9.8/shortcode_carousels.html this morning, it looks like what I want ! I will still search a little bit if it's doable with bootstrap, to avoid another dependency but if not, I will use owl ! Thank you for the help !

Comment: I think for your task it's more convenient to use Oul, than to retrain the Bootstrap.